# Azure AD B2C: update email for password reset

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We have for a customer an AAD B2C solution, and we've build a import tool that collects users from a source and creates them in AD B2C.

This is done via the Active Directory Graph Api, but we are having an issue when it comes to the Password forgotten flow.

```
{
    "accountEnabled": true,
    "signInNames": [
        {
            "type": "userName",
            "value": "****"
        }
    ],
    "passwordPolicies" : "DisablePasswordExpiration, DisableStrongPassword",
    "passwordProfile": {
        "password": "SomePassword",
        "forceChangePasswordNextLogin": false
    },
    "otherMails": ["****@****.net"],
    "creationType": "LocalAccount",
    "displayName": "*****",
    "givenName": "*****",
    "surname": "***** *****",
    "userPrincipalName": "PLH@vandeputprd.onmicrosoft.com",
    "extension_extensionID_ClientId": "***",
    "extension_extensionID_Language": "N"
}
```

The problem is that when we ask for email verification that this fails since the mail field is not set. If we try to set this, the API returns that this field is readonly

```
{
"odata.error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": {
        "lang": "en",
        "value": "Property 'mail' is read-only and cannot be set."
        },
        "requestId": "97b360eb-052e-4c16-8706-468b72ae1ebe",
        "date": "2019-10-11T10:50:01"
    }
}
```

We can set it manually in the AD B2C portal:
[image]

We have tried using the newer Microsoft Graph Api and looking into powershell scripts.

With powershell I was able to read it as **StrongAuthenticationUserDetails** but not able to set it.

Some options we are thinking about are:

- Looking for a way to populate this programatically
- Looking for a way to ask that on first logon
- Looking for sending invitation instead of prepopulating the userbase

The last option requires a lot of work, that is financially not an option.

Do someone has some ideas about how we can do/solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using a [JWT token](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/invoking-the-azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy-journey-with-a-jwt-e9e3ff0560a3) to validate the user instead of an email.

Note that the client_assertion method is being deprecated in favour of [id_token_hint](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/using-a-jwt-to-invoke-an-azure-ad-b2c-flow-using-id-token-hint-13752ee6d9df).

Comment: Thanks, this helps for the reset password, but not forgot password. But going to check this avenue. Thanks

Comment: Nevermind, I've judged to soon. This is what we need. Thanks a lot